# Ionic scroll area extends beyond the screen boundaries

Tags: html, css, angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

I have a page that I am trying to split into two sections using Ionic elements etc.: The top section is fixed, and has a set number of items that will not change, and the bottom section should be a scroll-able list. 
Also, I want to use an ion-refresher for the entire screen (of course if the user were to try and pull down on the bottom section, this would just scroll through that section..)

The problem I have is that when using an ion-scroll element for the bottom section, the scroll-able area extends beyond the bottom of the screen which means the bottom elements of the list are never view-able. Why is this?

Code:

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="false">
    <ion-refresher
        pulling-text="Pull to refresh..."
        ion-refresh="refresh()">
    </ion-refresher>
    <ion-list>  
        <ion-item class="item item-icon-left" href="#/somewhere"> 
            <i class="icon ion-icon"></i> Content
            <span class="badge badge-assertive>1</span>
        </ion-item> 
        <ion-item class="item item-icon-left" href="#/somewhere"> 
            <i class="icon ion-icon"></i> Content
            <span class="badge badge-assertive">2</span>
        </ion-item> 
        <ion-item class="item item-icon-left" href="#/somewhere">
            <i class="icon ion-icon"></i> Content
            <span class="badge badge-assertive">3</span>
        </ion-item>    
    </ion-list>
    <div id="myDivider" class="item-divider">               
        <i class="icon ion-icon"></i> I'm a divider
    </div>
    <ion-scroll id=myBottomScroll">             
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in myItems" 
              class="item" href="#/somewhere/{{item.id}}">
                <i class="icon ion-icon"></i> 
                <i class="icon ion-icon"></i> {{alert.What}}
                <i class="icon ion-icon" style="float: right"></i>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-scroll>    
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Set the height of the [ion-scroll](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/) directive (and ideally, the inner content).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't specifically set the heights of any items anywhere and want to keep this dynamic to cover multiple devices - how can I achieve this? All I know is that I will have a fixed number of Ionic list items at the top, plus the divider (and a nav-title), but I have not specified the heights for those. I want the scroll to fill the remaining space.

Comment: The directive needs a height to be set to work, so if you can't allocate a specific amount of space by css (using calc for example to subtract out the rendered height of your fixed elements from 100vh), then I guess you'll have to calculate the height on the fly of those fixed elements (via a directive) and use ng-style to set the height of the ion-scroll inline.  Make sure to include all of the fixed elements on the page including for example any headers/footers.